# Viewing all my posts with a particular tag

Tags: support

Is it possible to view all my posts with a particular tag? When I look under "Questions" in my profile, and click on a tag, it shows other users' posts with that tag.

Comment: Don't click a tag under the "questions" tab. You need to click a tag under the "tags" tab. You can also click a tag in the "Tags" section in the summary.

Comment: You mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1307086+%5Balgorithm%5D)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to your profile and click one of your tags you get what you want:

> [image]

It will show up in the search `user:1307086 [tagname]`

Answer (score 5):

You can simply type in the search box in the upper right:

```
user:me [tagname]
```

Comment: I love random downvotes. :D Ooh, and my rep count's finally a multiple of ten again! That's been annoying me for so long here *and* on SO

Comment: 7850 is even better isn't it?

Comment: @retailcoder Yay, multiple of 50 :D

Comment: 7777 could have been way cooler! You can still start 200 rep bounty, get 5 answer upvotes, one question upvote and accept an answer. :D

Comment: @Sha :P 8000 might be easier to achieve

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Hooray, 8000! :P Now nobody upvote me

Answer (score 0):

`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:<YOURUSERID>+[<TAGNAME>]`

Example URL: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:193130+[discussion]

This will show all questions and answers of yours within a specific tag.