# Activity tag badge redirecting instead to my posts with that tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, profile-page

In the Activity profile I see

[image: upper part of activity profile page]

If I click in the badge "review" it goes to the [general "review" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review?sort=unanswered)

[image: page for questions tagged with "review"]

In my opinion would be great to go instead to my posts with "review" tag, in case anyone wants to help me accomplish that badge for whatever reason. Asking here because the same thought process applies to Stack Overflow, for example (where I first felt the need).

Note: [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195033/364217) wanted to see all the badges by clicking there, as in it'd be intuitive to work that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It goes to the general [review](/questions/tagged/review) page because it's meant to be a guide for *you* to increase your score and/or number of answers in that tag.

> in case anyone wants to help me accomplish that badge for whatever reason.

First of all, one of the golden rules of Stack Exchange is ["vote for the content, not for the user"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232). A related advice is "don't vote on posts you visit from a user's profile" (IIRC, @Undo posted that somewhere but I can't find it). IMHO the system should not support this kind of voting behavior; I see only downsides to this feature request.

Second, have you tried clicking badges on other user's profiles (or your own when not logged in, e.g. in a private browser window)? Surprise, surprise: *there is no link at all*:

[image]